# Ruby - Formatting json into string

Tags: json, ruby

I need to convert a JSON response into a well-formatted string, more like a table.

Example,

```
[{id: 1, name: "Panda", description: ""}, {id: 2, name: "koala", description: ""},...]
```

To be converted as,

```
 Id       | Name        |Description
 1        | Panda       |
 2        | Koala test  |
```

and for the text to be automatically wrapped inside the cell width. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: It's more of Javascript(Client side work) than Ruby

Comment: Look on ruby gems in the table printing category

Comment: First step: `JSON.load(json_string)`. Second step: Something like [`text-table`](https://github.com/aptinio/text-table).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse JSON result.

```
data = JSON.parse(result)
```

Then use that parsed result to generate the pattern.

```
data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Panda', description: '' },
  { id: 2, name: 'koala', description: '' }
]

puts 'Id      | Name         |Description'
data.each do |entry|
  puts "#{entry[:id]}       | #{entry[:name]}        |#{entry[:description]}"
end
```

Hope this helps!